# Использование choice_set.all с несколькими ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, model

Есть модели с нескольким ForeignKey, как использовать choice_set.all чтобы получать нужные объекты

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id_question = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=160)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text


class Answer(models.Model):
    id_answer = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=160)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text

class Choice(models.Model):
    id_choice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{}_{}'.format(self.question, self.answer)
```

Например во view или в html файле

```
{% for answer in question.choice_set.all %}
    <label>{{ answer.text }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрос `question.choice_set.all` вернёт набор Choice, но не Answer. Чтобы добраться до текста ответа, наверное, нужно сделать так:

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <label>{{ choice.answer.text }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Чтобы получить все ответы на конкретный вопрос:

```
{% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
    <label>{{ answer.text }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Choice хранит выбранный ответ, а мне нужно список ответов к данному вопросу

Comment: Ок, если я правильно вас понял, то можно сделать еще проще и choice_set.all тут не нужен. Я отредактировал свой ответ, взгляните.